# How could Mr.0 not recognize Sanji?

Tags: one-piece

When Sanji finds out Mr.3's hut in Little Garden, he answers a call by Mr.0, who mistakes him for Mr.3 himself.

We know that den den mushis look like whoever's speaking at the other side of the line, so Mr.0 (who should know who his subordinates are) should have recognized that it was not Mr.3

Is it maybe a special den den mushi that does not show the likeness of the individual, for the sake of not letting anyone know who Mr.0 is, or is there a different explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking on the right track except for the fact that den-den mushis do not imitate those speaking. Den-den mushis do not "take the shape" of their owners. They are customized by the owners to show ownership. Trafalgar's den-den mushi looked like him, so did Doflamingo's. Thats why Mr. 0 could not recognize that it was Sanji on the other side of the line instead of Mr. 3. Also because of plot.

[Source](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Den_Den_Mushi)

Comment: A small caveat. While it is true, that they don't take on the exact shape, they do mimic distinctive facial traits and even injuries (for example Zoro's scar).

Comment: When Doflamingo and Law are speaking over den-den mushi after Punk Hazard (chapter 697), the Law-looking den-den mushi's eye change to look like Caesar's eye when he is screaming.